# I am trying to fetch one field looking at another field using XSLT Maps

Tags: streaming, accumulator, xslt-3.0

I am trying to use streaming (XSLT 3.0) to process the report output because of huge volume. I have to use XSLT because of specific output format. While transforming the report output, I need to lookup "Supplier_Invoice_number" based on a combination of Customer_Invoice and Supplier stored in "Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier" at the line level. I need to show "Supplier_Invoice_number" at the line level.

I have created XSLT maps to store the value of  "Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier" and "Supplier_Invoice_number" so that while transforming the lines i can fetch "Supplier_Invoice_number" to then show at the line level in the output. Below is the XSLT I have created, but I am getting blank for "Supplier_Invoice_number". I am new to XSLT maps and streaming, therefore would really appreciate if someone can guide me to the solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:wd1="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Lookup_Supplier_Invoice_for_Customer_Invoice" xmlns:wd2="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Customer_Invoices_to_Connect" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="SupplierInvoiceLookup CurrentLookupValue"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupValue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd1:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier/text()" select="."/>
</xsl:accumulator>
<xsl:accumulator name="SupplierInvoiceLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd1:Supplier_Invoice_Number/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('CurrentLookupValue'))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="AggregatedData">
    <xsl:for-each select="wd2:Report_Data/wd2:Report_Entry/copy-of()">
        <xsl:text>{&#10;        "Company": "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd2:Company"/>            
        <xsl:iterate select="wd2:lines">
            <xsl:text>      {&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>        "sequence": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd2:sequence"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>        "sales_item_id": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd2:sales_item_id"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>                
            <xsl:text>        "supplier_invoice_no": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="supplier_invoice_no" select="accumulator-before('SupplierInvoiceLookup')( normalize-space( @wd2:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier ) )"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('SupplierInvoiceLookup')( normalize-space( @wd2:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier ) )"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:iterate>            
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>  &#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AggregatedData>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Lookup_Supplier_Invoice_for_Customer_Invoice">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Supplier_Invoice_Lines_group>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>INV-201900000024Dell Receivables LP</wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>
                <wd:Supplier_Invoice_Number>SI-00000047</wd:Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            </wd:Supplier_Invoice_Lines_group>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Supplier_Invoice_Lines_group>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>INV-201900000024Charles Case [C]</wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>
                <wd:Supplier_Invoice_Number>SI-00000050</wd:Supplier_Invoice_Number>
            </wd:Supplier_Invoice_Lines_group>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Customer_Invoices_to_Connect">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Company>Financial/wd:Company>
            <wd:lines>
                <wd:sequence>a8</wd:sequence>
                <wd:sales_item_id>Data - Enterprise License</wd:sales_item_id>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>INV-201900000024Dell Receivables LP</wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>
            </wd:lines>
            <wd:lines>
                <wd:sequence>a9</wd:sequence>
                <wd:sales_item_id>TBA Trade Reports ATS Cncl</wd:sales_item_id>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>INV-201900000024Charles Case [C]</wd:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier>
            </wd:lines>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
</AggregatedData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you have used `@wd2:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier` to select an attribute although your input has element data, so I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="AggregatedData">
    <xsl:for-each select="wd2:Report_Data/wd2:Report_Entry/copy-of()">
        <xsl:text>{&#10;        "Company": "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd2:Company"/>            
        <xsl:iterate select="wd2:lines">
            <xsl:text>      {&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>        "sequence": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd2:sequence"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>        "sales_item_id": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd2:sales_item_id"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>                
            <xsl:text>        "supplier_invoice_no": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('SupplierInvoiceLookup')( normalize-space( wd2:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier ) )"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:iterate>            
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>  &#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

And I think you want the map to be the other way around in terms of key and values so the accumulators would do

```
<xsl:accumulator name="CurrentLookupValue" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd1:Customer_Invoice_and_Supplier/text()" select="string()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
<xsl:accumulator name="SupplierInvoiceLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd1:Supplier_Invoice_Number/text()" select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('CurrentLookupValue'), string(.))"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mu

If you want to output JSON then note that XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 maps and arrays and the output method `json` does allow that in a comfortable way without struggling to output pairs of braces and element names. But that might be better solved in a separate question where you show us the JSON you want.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your inputs. It worked. I started off with the map definition that you have mentioned but did not realize @ at the start of the expression was causing the issue. I am planning to switch to  XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 maps, arrays with JSON output once I am sure that XSLT would be able to handle the volume.

Do you think perfomance could be an issue with this XSLT if we have below volumes ?

1. Close to 50,000 rows that needs to be loaded to XSLT maps.
2. XSLT needs to process close to 40,000 Header rows and 500,000 lines

Comment: I can't really estimate performance. You haven't provided any details on the used software. Do you use Saxon 9 EE? I am sure if you ask a new question tagged for [tag:saxon] then Michael Kay can help if needed. What is a "header" in that XML input, a `wd:Report_Entry` in the namespace `urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Lookup_Supplier_Invoice_for_Customer_Invoice`? What is a "row"? You are using `wd2:Report_Data/wd2:Report_Entry/copy-of()`, are all these `wd2:Report_Entry` as small as shown? Or can there be lots of `wd:lines` in a single entry?

Comment: Ok, I can open a new question. Yes, "wd:Report_Entry" would be header and there can be few thousands lines within each entry.

Comment: I think this problem with the map use is solved and you can accept the answer.  For further questions on performance or the exact JSON output if that is what you need I think it is better to raise new, separate questions with the necessary details.